# Constexpr constructible function object

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, type-erasure, std-function

I have a question somewhat similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53977787/constexpr-version-of-stdfunction), but for a more limited case which I believe should be possible somehow: I want to construct a static constexpr array of function calls from a number of lambdas, each sharing the same signature. The static and constexpr part is important here since I'm on an embedded system, where I want to make sure such tables end up in Flash.

So basically what I want to do is

```
#include<vector>
#include<functional>
#include<variant>

using params_t = std::vector<std::variant<int, float /*maybe others*/ >>;

struct command_t {
   using callable_t = std::function<void(params_t)>;

  const callable_t func;
   //other members..
};

class AClass {
    template<typename func_t>
    constexpr static command_t::callable_t make_callable(func_t fun) {
         return [fun](params_t params){/*construct a call to fun using params and template magic*/};
    }

    static void mycommand();
    static void mycommand2(int i);

    //The following fails: 
    ///"error: in-class initialization of static data member 'const command_t AClass::commands [2]' of non-literal type"
    static constexpr command_t commands[2] = {command_t{make_callable(mycommand)},
                                              command_t{make_callable(mycommand2)}};
};
```

[On coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1839d8a6f69242ea)

Note that the type erasure here is quite limited, since the signature of the lambda varies only by the signature of the capture of `fun`. The function call obviously doesn't (and cannot) need to be constexpr, only the construction.

So basically my question is can I somehow make the `commands` array `static constexpr`, either somehow using `std::function,` or something like [inplace_function](https://github.com/WG21-SG14/SG14/blob/master/SG14/inplace_function.h), or perhaps by spinning my own code for type-erasing the lambda in this specific case?

Comment: Lambas without a capture can be converted to standard function pointers. That also means you can get rid of the `std::function` objects, which aren't constexpr. So you'd have `using callable_t = void (*)(params_t);`. I'm not sure what the `make_callable` is supposed to do.

Comment: @Darhuuk Note that the lambda does have a capture. `make_callable` is in reality a template: `fun` can have any number and types of arguments, and `make_callable` constructs a lambda which calls `fun` with params coming from the vector of variants given as an argument (which obviously must match the signature of `fun`, which is checked at runtime).

Comment: Ah, I see. So is the goal to "automate" this? Because it seems to me that if you write out each lambda by hand, there's no need to capture `fun` (since they're static functions).

Comment: @Darhuuk Exactly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, this is not possible since the capture of a lambda can get arbitrary large and hence, at some point we need a heap allocation which then kills any hopes of constexpr pre-C++20 (and I don't think C++20 will help much for this case, either).

But you only want to capture a function pointer if I see this right and that we can do:

```
#include <vector>
 #include<variant>

using params_t = std::vector<std::variant<int, float /*maybe others*/ >>;

struct command_t {
   using callable_t = void (*)(std::vector<params_t>); 

  const callable_t func;
   //other members..
};

 template<auto f> 
 void wrap(std::vector<params_t>){
    // make this dependent of f, maybe use function_traits for fancy stuff
 }
class AClass {

    static void mycommand();
    static void mycommand2(int i);

    static constexpr command_t commands[2] = {wrap<mycommand>, wrap<mycommand2>};
};

 int main() {

 }
```

Thanks to xskxzr for valuable suggestions.

Comment: That looks promising, I'll give it a go tomorrow! I think you shouldn't have `&` in front of the function name when calling do_wrap?

Comment: When `f` is declared as a function parameter, it can't be known at compile time, so it can't be used as a template argument. This is the reason why your `do_wrap` does not work. By the way, why do you need the `wrapper` class? Is there any problem to declare `template<auto f> void wrap(std::vector<int>);` directly?

Comment: `auto f` is C++20 and we want to extract the arguments, I think.

Comment: It's C++17, and you can also extract `Args...` using [`function_traits`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9065203/5376789) on `decltype(f)`.

Comment: Ah, then I had something wrong in mind. Yes this simplifies stuff. I will rework the answer.

Comment: It works, thanks! The `auto f` caused some trouble as I had to rewrite the "magic" part which extracts all the function stuff, but it's done now.

Answer (score 0):

Since `mycommanN` have different signatures and you need to capture them, I don't see a way to have a constexpr vector. Maybe someone can come up with a better design.

I have a solution: use `std::tuple`. But I don't really like as it is really cumbersome to work with `tuple` as a container. For instance iterating over it is ... let's say not a walk in the park. Anyway, here it is in case it does help:

```
using params_t = std::vector<std::variant<int, float /*maybe others*/>>;

// I needed to lift this out of AClass because of ... complicated reasons
// (short version: when both are AClass members
//    the return type of `make_command` is not resolved in the init of `commands`
//    because both are static, `commands` is not a template and `make_command` is a template
//    tbh I don't know exactly what is happening. It's one of those dark corners of C++)

template <class RealFunc>
static constexpr auto make_command(RealFunc real_func) {
  return [real_func](params_t params) { /*magic*/ };
}

struct AClass {
  static void mycommand();
  static void mycommand2(int i);

  static constexpr std::tuple commands{make_command(mycommand),
                                       make_command(mycommand2)};
};

// usage
auto test() {
  constexpr auto command0 = std::get<0>(AClass::commands<>);

  params_t params0 = {};

  return command0(command0);
}
```

Comment: Tuple doesn't work, because then the code using the commands table would be dependent on the types of all the possible commands, and that's what I want to avoid.