# Template of Ret ( Class::*member )( Args... )

Tags: c++, templates, reflection

What would the be within the comments to make

```
property( "prop", &Class::getter, &Class::setter );
```

compile? This is the definition of property

```
template< typename Class, 
          typename Get,
          typename Set,
          typename = std::enable_if< std::is_same< 
              Get,
              typename std::remove_cv< typename std::remove_reference< typename std::remove_pointer< Set >::type >::type >::type >::value
          > 
>
constexpr auto property (
    const char* name,
    reflection::function< /* Get ( Class::* )() */ > getter,
    reflection::function< /* Get ( Class::* )( Set ) */ > setter
) {
    return nullptr;
}
```

I'm working on a constexpr function as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61191826/16725187) except I would like to pass a class method as the argument. The one detailed there is useful for lambdas but I am looking for a class member.

reflection::function is defined as

```
template< typename > class function;

template < typename Class, typename Ret, typename ... Args >
class function < Ret ( Class::* ) ( Args... ) > {
public:
    constexpr function( Ret ( Class::*method )( Args... ) ) {
    
    }

    /* impl */
    
};
```

Comment: Assuming `Class::getter` is a method, (it is not directly a `reflection::function<T>`), then you cannot deduce the template parameter.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: Do you need `reflection::function<T>`? Can't you take directly pointer on member?

Comment: I think that may be the better solution.

Comment: See [template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions).